# 'o' and 'O' commands don't work properly

Tags: vim

Pressing `o` and `O` (opening new line below and above the cursor) stopped working properly for some reason. Sometimes they work as expected, but on many (or rather most) occasions they behave like described below:

- `O` opens new line above the cursor, but the cursor jumps to the end
  of the first non-empty line above the cursor (it should jump to the
  beginning of the opened line)
- `o` opens new line below the cursor, but the cursor jumps to the line where the cursor is, or to the end of the first non empty-line above the current line if current line is empty (consist only of whitespace) (again the cursor should jump to the beginning of the opened line)

To illustrate. `[]` marks the cursor position.

```
line   1
line[] 2
line   3
```

Pressing `o`:

```
line   1
line   2[]

line   3
```

Pressing 'O' from the first situation:

```
line  1[]

line  2
line  3
```

What could be the reason of that behaviour/problem? I would like to get back the default behaviour of `o` and `O`.

Comment: Try using  the command `vim -u NONE` to open vim without a configuration file loaded. Then try these commands. If they work then (like they do in my machine), it's something in your configuration file.

Comment: @Ben Okay, so I did that and found that the line of ~/.vimrc that does that causes the problem (removing it, removes the problem) is `filetype plugin indent on`. I have this problem for example when editing HTML and my ~/.vim/after/ftlplugin/html.vim is: `setlocal shiftwidth=2 ; setlocal tabstop=2`. In my ~/.vimrc I also have lines: `set noexpandtab ; set shiftwidth=4 ; set tabstop=4 ; set autoindent`. The expected behaviour was to insert TABs instead of spaced and have them rendered at 4 spaces wide by default, but 2 in HTML. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't think that could cause it- I have the same options set in my `.vimrc` and I'm fine. Are you using non-built-in plugins?

Comment: I found that the removing `set autoindent` also removes the problem and brings the default behaviour of `o` and `O`. Still I don't understand why... Maybe the problem really lies somewhere else. Yes, I'm using few plugins: vim-commentary, vim-visual-star-search, vim-unimpaired, vim-surround, vim-fugitive.

Comment: Like I said, I have the same options set in my `.vimrc` and I'm fine. Who am I to argue with success though :) ? If your configuration is online somwhere, I'll bookmark it and look at it when I have time.

Comment: @Ben Here's my vimrc: http://www.pastebin.ca/3760682

Comment: @Ben And here's the content of my `~/.vim/` directory to show, which plugins do I use: http://www.pastebin.ca/3760691 . What is in `~/.vim/bundle-for-later` is not currently used.

Comment: I looked at it and made some alterations- I'm not going to try to recreate your `bundle` directory, so I commented out your pathogen line. I got some errors that I also commented out. It works now, so something I did was effective- http://www.pastebin.ca/3760700.
Search 'bbkane' to see my changes. If you're getting all of your plugins from Github, I recommend [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)  instead of Pathogen. In my experience it's faster, easier to use, and makes transferring your configuration (plugins and all) between machines *much* easier.

Comment: If the problem is in your plugins, Smart-Tabs might be the offender. It affects whitespace. Maybe try removing that too.